# Can I get the same result using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

Currently i use Javascript to replace a small part of any link that has similarity to a domain (ex: othersite.com)
I want to know how I can do this same effect, but in JQUERY. Is it possible?
I just want to change a small portion, without affecting the rest of the link.
As I can have this same result in Jquery (using Jquery)?
I hope someone can help, thanks.

This is my Javascript code:

```
    function changetext(){
    var id = "JOSH";
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i = link.length;
    while(i--){
        var lnk = link[i].href;
        if (lnk.match("othersite.com")) {
            link[i].href = lnk.replace(/name=[^&]*/g, 'name='+id);
        }
    }  
}
changetext();
```

..

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=susan1&last=3">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=PAtrIck01&lat=6">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=1Smith&lat=49">Text</a>
```

Using Javascript effect, is as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=JOSH&last=3">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=JOSH&lat=6">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=JOSH&lat=49">Text</a>
```

As I can have this same result in Jquery (using Jquery)?
...... thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to switch to using jQuery for that code? the way it currently is should be far more efficient than using jQuery, and isn't much harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, there's nothing wrong into using "vanilla-js" in a jQuery codebase.
The use case in this case is so simple that you shouldn't incur into cross-browser compatibility issues.

Anyway the snippet below should be equivalent to the one you've posted.

```
function fixAnchorHrefForJosh ($a) {
  $a.attr("href",
    $a.attr("href").replace(/name=[^&]*/g, "name=JOSH"));
}

function fixAnchorsHref () {
  $("a")
    .filter(function (i, el) {
      return $(el).attr("href").match("othersite.com")
    })
    .each(function (i, el) {
      fixAnchorHrefForJosh($(el));
    });
}

// Register an handler
// that will be executed when the DOM is loaded.
$(document).ready(fixAnchorsHref);
```

You could think of [$.fn.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), and [$.fn.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as the jQuery equivalents of `Array#filter`, `Array#forEach`... but don't let you be fooled, there are differences, eg. the order of the arguments of the callback.

[$.fn.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) works as getter/setter for the attribute of an element. That's a common pattern in jQuery, eg. `$.fn.css`, `$.fn.height`...

```js
function fixAnchorHrefForJosh($a) {
  $a.attr("href",
    $a.attr("href").replace(/name=[^&]*/g, "name=JOSH"));
}

function fixAnchorsHref() {
  $("a")
    .filter(function(i, el) {
      return $(el).attr("href").match("othersite.com")
    })
    .each(function(i, el) {
      fixAnchorHrefForJosh($(el));
    });
}

// Register an handler
// that will be executed when the DOM is loaded.
$(document).ready(fixAnchorsHref);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a:after {
  content: attr(href);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=susan1&last=3">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=PAtrIck01&lat=6">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.asite.com/?name=1Smith&lat=49">Text</a>
<a href="http://www.othersite.com/?name=1Smith&lat=49">Text</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Bruno,

I'm trying to test the code you have given me,
but apparently did not change links.

Am I doing something wrong? .. I'm new to Jquery, apologies.
What am I doing wrong?

Link demo:
http://www.my-xio.info/demo.html

Comment: I don't believe that will actually assign the modified `href` value back to the element. You will need to wrap that line with `$(this).attr('href', <new value>);`. See http://jsfiddle.net/sRdCM/

Comment: Hello @Travesty3

I just saw that in your link works very well what I want, but not because in my DEMO does not work .. Am I missing something? .. sorry I'm new to jquery. Thanks: See Link Demo:  http://my-xio.info/demo02.html

Comment: You need to wrap that code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block, so that it fires when the Document is ready. jsFiddle does that automatically. See edit.

Comment: READY !!, I found a link on the internet of a "jquery-1.3.2.min.js"
  And it works, thank you very much @Travesty3  : http://my-xio.info/demo02.html  .. Thank you Bruno too <3 !!